# Override the ChannelProcessingFilter with Spring Security 3.0.5 does not work

Tags: spring-security

The default behavior of the Channel Processors is to do a sendRedirect (which is redirect temporary with 302 code). I need to change this behavior so that a permanent (301) redirect is done instead of 302 redirect. I tried to do the following:

1. Create a custom ChannelProcessingFilter by extending the ChannelProcessingFilter:

   ```java
   public class MyChannelProcessingFilter extends ChannelProcessingFilter{
      //No implementation, I needed this to just make sure that a custom filter is created and I can configure it as a custom filter in the xml file. 
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom EntryPoint by extending the AbstractRetryEntryPoint

   ```java
   public class RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint extends org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.AbstractRetryEntryPoint {
       private PortResolver portResolver = new PortResolverImpl();
       private final String scheme ="https://";
       /** The standard port for the scheme (80 for http, 443 for https) */
       private final int standardPort = 443;

       public RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint() {
           super("https://", 443);
       }

       @Override
       public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
           String queryString = request.getQueryString();
           String redirectUrl = request.getRequestURI() + ((queryString == null) ? "" : ("?" + queryString));

           Integer currentPort = new Integer(portResolver.getServerPort(request));
           Integer redirectPort = getMappedPort(currentPort);

           if (redirectPort != null) {
               boolean includePort = redirectPort.intValue() != standardPort;

               redirectUrl = scheme + request.getServerName() + ((includePort) ? (":" + redirectPort) : "") + redirectUrl;
           }

           if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
               logger.debug("Redirecting to: " + redirectUrl);
           }

           res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
           res.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
           res.setHeader("Connection", "close");
       }

       protected Integer getMappedPort(Integer mapFromPort) {
           return getPortMapper().lookupHttpsPort(mapFromPort);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Configure the same in the applicationContext-security.xml file. I am putting the complete xml file for your reference (removing the parts that are not needed. If you require the other parts do let me know)

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

       <security:http auto-config="false" 
               entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
               access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/activ8/protectedCheckEligibility.html**" access="user" requires-channel="https"/>
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/siteMap.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="http"/>
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/privacyPolicy.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="http"/>
           <!-- other urls configured over here -->
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user" requires-channel="https"/>
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="https"/>
           <security:intercept-url pattern="/fb_activities.html**" access="parent" />       

           <security:remember-me key="appfuseRocks" />
           <security:custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="careSwitchUserProcessingFilter"/>
           <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter"/>
           <!-- configured the custom channel filter over here --> 
           <security:custom-filter position="CHANNEL_FILTER" ref="myChannelProcessingFilter"/>
       </security:http>

       <bean id="myChannelProcessingFilter" class="com.my.webapp.filter.myChannelProcessingFilter">
           <property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager" />
           <property name="securityMetadataSource">
               <security:filter-security-metadata-source path-type="ant">
                   <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL" />
               </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
           </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
           <property name="channelProcessors">
               <list>
                   <ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
               </list>
           </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor">
           <property name="entryPoint" ref="secureChannelEntryPoint"/>
           <!-- <property name="portMapper" ref="portMapper" /> -->
           <property name="secureKeyword" value="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="secureChannelEntryPoint" class="com.my.webapp.filter.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint"/>

       <!-- lot of other configuratons... removed -->

   </beans>
   ```

I am getting following errors when I try to run my tomcat:

```
ERROR 2011-12-26 21:13:21,569 [ina].[localhost].[/]]: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.kajeet.webapp.listener.StartupListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Filter beans '' and 'Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null' have the same 'order' value. When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from  and avoiding the use of .
    Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.kajeet.webapp.listener.StartupListener.contextInitialized(StartupListener.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

I have also overridden other filters and it does not complain about those. This application was running perfectly fine before. We had this additional requirement and hence I added the new filter and ran into such errors.

Second approach that I tried is just configuring the default ChannelProcessingFilter in the XML, since in Spring 3.0 the filters are automatically called, I was under impression that I can configure them in XML file and spring will automatically load them, but it didn't:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <security:http auto-config="false" 
                entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
                access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/activ8/protectedCheckEligibility.html**" access="user" requires-channel="https"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/siteMap.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="http"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/privacyPolicy.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="http"/>
            <!-- other urls configured over here -->
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user" requires-channel="https"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" requires-channel="https"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/fb_activities.html**" access="parent" />       

            <security:remember-me key="appfuseRocks" />
            <security:custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="careSwitchUserProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myCustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter"/>
        </security:http>

        <bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.securechannel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
            <property name="channelProcessors">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
                    <ref bean="insecureChannelProcessor"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor"/>
        <bean id="insecureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.InsecureChannelProcessor"/> 

        <!-- lot of other configuratons... removed -->

    </beans>
```

Any help will be definitely appreciated. I am not a Spring pro, but I have done some work on it, a pointer or two may definitely help me to resolve this. Thank you in advance

Comment: On further study, I got to know that this does not require extending the ChannelProcessingFilter, the issue I found was that the SecureChannelProcessor is initailzed twice, once with the default values and second time with custom values that is part of the XML. When applying rules it just uses the one with default values. Seems like I am missing a very small link somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

The issue is that we cannot have both the security:http as well as the myChannelProcessingFilter (the one I had overridden) to deal with the access argument of the security:intercept-url, hence I removed the http tag and added the access thing in the myChannelProcessingFilter, where I wanted it to process. The XML that resolved it is follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- 
        The http element responsible for creating a FilterChainProxy and the filter beans which it uses. 
        Common problems like incorrect filter ordering are no longer an issue as the filter positions are predefined. 
    -->
    <security:http auto-config="false" 
            entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >

        <security:custom-filter position="CHANNEL_FILTER" ref="channelProcessingFilter"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.html*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user"  />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,user,admin" />


    </security:http>

    <bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
      <property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager"/>
      <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source path-type="ant">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp**" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html**" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL" />
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
        <property name="channelProcessors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="secureProcessor"/>
                <ref bean="insecureProcessor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="secureProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor" >
        <property name="entryPoint" ref="retryWithHttps"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="insecureProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.InsecureChannelProcessor">
        <property name="entryPoint" ref="retryWithHttp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="retryWithHttps" class="com.my.webapp.filter.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="retryWithHttp" class="com.my.webapp.filter.RetryWithHttpEntryPoint" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to achieve the same thing with much less code and complexity. You can simply use a `BeanPostProcessor` to get the `SecureChannelProcessor` and `InsecureChannelProcessor` and then set your own entry point on them. That way, you can still use the defaults on everything else.

The BeanPostProcessor:

```java
@Component
public class ChannelProcessorsPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof SecureChannelProcessor) ((SecureChannelProcessor)bean).setEntryPoint(new MyEntryRetryPoint("https://", 443));
        else if (bean instanceof InsecureChannelProcessor) ((InsecureChannelProcessor)bean).setEntryPoint(new MyEntryRetryPoint("http://", 80));

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to write a redirect strategy:

```
@Component
public class PermanentRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {
    private boolean contextRelative;

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", response.encodeRedirectURL(calculateRedirectUrl(request.getContextPath(), url)));
    }

    /**
     * Unfortunately DefaultRedirectStrategy.calculateRedirectUrl is private
     * If this weren't the case, we could extend this class from DefaultRedirectStrategy
     * to use its method directly without copying it
     */
    private String calculateRedirectUrl(String contextPath, String url) {
        if (!UrlUtils.isAbsoluteUrl(url)) {
            if (contextRelative) {
                return url;
            } else {
                return contextPath + url;
            }
        }

        // Full URL, including http(s)://

        if (!contextRelative) {
            return url;
        }

        // Calculate the relative URL from the fully qualified URL, minus the last
        // occurence of the scheme and base context
        url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("://") + 3); // strip off scheme
        url = url.substring(url.indexOf(contextPath) + contextPath.length());

        if (url.length() > 1 && url.charAt(0) == '/') {
            url = url.substring(1);
        }

        return url;
    }
}
```

and then setting it to the existing entry point:

```
@Component
public class ChannelProcessorsPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private RedirectStrategy permanentRedirectStrategy;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        ChannelEntryPoint entryPoint = null;

        if (bean instanceof SecureChannelProcessor) {
            entryPoint = ((SecureChannelProcessor) bean).getEntryPoint();
        } else if (bean instanceof InsecureChannelProcessor) {
            entryPoint = ((InsecureChannelProcessor) bean).getEntryPoint();
        }

        if (entryPoint != null && AbstractRetryEntryPoint.class.isAssignableFrom(entryPoint.getClass())) {
            ((AbstractRetryEntryPoint) entryPoint).setRedirectStrategy(permanentRedirectStrategy);
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```