# How to change HTTP status code when Spring Security's "requires-channel" directive is used?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to enforce that certain URLs under my webapp are only accessible by HTTPS, while the rest are only accessible by HTTP. I achieved this with Spring Security 3.1.1 using the following configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/cart" requires-channel="https" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" requires-channel="https" />
```

With this configuration, when I try to open "/login" under HTTP, I get automatically redirected to "/login" under HTTPS, which is exactly as required. Problem is the status code - redirect is performed with 302 (moved temporary). Is it possible to change that status code to 301 (moved permanently)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem has been described in greater details and answered here: [Override the ChannelProcessingFilter with Spring Security 3.0.5 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641867/override-the-channelprocessingfilter-with-spring-security-3-0-5-does-not-work)

Edit: Another approach is to leave the default retryWithHttpEntryPoint and retryWithHttpsEntryPoint beans and only provide a custom RedirectStrategy implementation.